# How to deploy Xamarin app to iPhone given Mac OS in VMWare?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I have installed Mac OS into a VMWare VM on my PC, got the Mac OS VM running XCode as necessary to be a build host for iOS.

I've been able to create a "Hello World" app in Xamarin and see it run in an iPhone simulator in Visual Studio 2019 on my PC.

Can I use this set up to deploy to an actual iPhone, or do I need to physically tether the target iPhone to a real Mac in order to deploy? If I can do it with my existing set up, how?

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately** , Such set up seems to be impossible.

> Can I use this set up to deploy to an actual iPhone

No , because this set up PC can not pair to VMWare's Mac. If want to deploy in iphone , first need to pair to Mac.Then PC can find the connected iPhone.

> or do I need to physically tether the target iPhone to a real Mac in order to deploy

Yes , you need to use a actual Mac. And here is the [Pairing to Mac for Xamarin.iOS development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) document.

> If I can do it with my existing set up, how?

Not using VS in PC to deploy. You need to install VisualStudio For Mac at least to deploy the connected iPhone.